# Summarize low values into one

Tags: pyspark

I have a table that looks something like this:

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| optionA | 123 |
| optionB | 50 |
| optionC | 32 |
| optionD | 4 |
| optionE | 2 |
| optionF | 1 |

I don't need the specifics about values lower that 10. So I just want to merge those values into one with the name "other" and the sum of those low values. Result would look like this:

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| optionA | 123 |
| optionB | 50 |
| optionC | 32 |
| other | 7 |

What's the easiest way to do that in databricks using pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do

```
name = F.expr("IF (value < 10, 'other', name)")
df.withColumn('name', name).groupby('name').agg(F.sum('value').alias('value'))
```

---

```
+-------+-----+
|   name|value|
+-------+-----+
|optionA|  123|
|optionB|   50|
|optionC|   32|
|  other|    7|
+-------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split your dataframe but your treshold (in this case 10), then calculate values for both df's and union them back together

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, sum

data = [("optionA", 123), ("optionB", 50), ("optionC", 32), ("optionD", 4), ("optionE", 2), ("optionF", 1)]
columns = ["name", "value"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

filtered_df = df.filter(col("value") >= 10)

low_values_sum = df.filter(col("value") < 10).agg(sum("value")).collect()[0][0]

other_row = spark.createDataFrame([("other", low_values_sum)], columns)
result_df = filtered_df.union(other_row)

result_df.show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+-----+
|   name|value|
+-------+-----+
|optionA|  123|
|optionB|   50|
|optionC|   32|
|  other|    7|
+-------+-----+
```